# How to create multiple records at once in Rails for coupon codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my app users should be able to create a set of x SecureRandom.hex(3) codes (to be used as coupons). What I want to do is to present a view to the user where he can input a number, e. g. 200, an then the app creates 200 different SecureRandom.hex(3) codes and save them to a database.

I think I would add a number field to my form, where the user can enter the number of codes he want and then pass this as a param to the controller.

My question now: how should my create action look like to achieve that the app then creates 200 records of SecureRandom.hex(3) codes?

Comment: how about `params[:count].to_i.times do .... code .... end` ? (assuming you get the number the user entered in `params[:count]`)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def create
  count = params[:count].to_i
  return "Not a valid number" unless count.is_a?(Integer) && count.positive?

  count.times do 
    Coupon.create(code: SecureRandom.hex(3)) # or whatever your model name is
  end
end
```

However, it's better if you create all the coupons in a background job for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a simple Coupon model which holds the hex as an attribute.
2. Add a new route for the action in routes.rb

   ```
   post '/coupons/create_multiple', to: 'coupons#create_multiple'
   ```
3. create the action in your controller coupons_controller.rb

   ```
   def create_multiple
     amount = params[:count].to_i
     if amount > 0
       amount.times do Coupon.create
     end
   end
   ```
4. Doing the "hex"-magic in the model coupon.rb

   ```
   before_validation :generate_code
   protected
   def generate_code
       self.code = SecureRandom.hex(3)
   end
   ```

With the model structure, you can now easily add validations or you can add more attributes to represent the status of the coupon.

**Btw:** You should give the whole a limit, because otherwise you have to add the creating into a background job.